# Override annotation and JDK 1.5

Tags: java, annotations, overriding

I'm using JDK 1.5, here is my class:

```
public final class Account implements ICAccount

{
//...
   @Override
   public ObjectID getId()
   {
      return new ObjectID(id);
   }
//...
}
```

`Account` overrides method `getId()` from `ICAccount`

But compilation fails.

```
Account.java  method does not override a method from its superclass
```

If i'm using JDK 1.6 the compilation succeeds.

In documentation to @Override annotation I see

```
Since:
1.5
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Override annotation is only used when overriding methods from classes in java 1.5. It also works for implementation of interface methods from Java 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 1.5 the `@Override` annotation is not allowed for methods that implement an interface method, only for methods that in fact override methods from a superclass. This changed in Java 1.6.