# Why is javac -source 1.5 allowing @Override on interface methods?

Tags: java, java-6, java-5

Here is some sample java code that is illegal under 1.5, if I understand correctly
(since [`@Override` could not be used for overrides of interface methods until java 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498769/override-annotation-and-jdk-1-5/)):

```
public class A { 
  public static interface MyInterface { 
    public void myInterfaceMethod();
  }
  public static class MyClass implements MyInterface { 
    @Override public void myInterfaceMethod() {}
  }
}
```

I want to find all such 1.5-incompatibilities in my source code,
so I installed a java1.5-capable compiler on my ubuntu linux machine:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
JAVAROOT=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
${JAVAROOT}/bin/javac -version
# javac 1.8.0_232
```

and compiled the above java source code:

```
${JAVAROOT}/bin/javac -source 1.5 -Xlint:all -Xlint:-options A.java
```

I expected the above java code to be rejected.  But it
apparently compiled successfully, in spite of the illegality under 1.5.

What's going on?  Am I misunderstanding the 1.5 rules about `@Override`?
Or am I misunderstanding what `-source 1.5` is supposed to do?

FWIW, I notice that `-source 1.4` does give the expected error:

```
${JAVAROOT}/bin/javac -source 1.4 -Xlint:all -Xlint:-options A.java
A.java:6: error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.4
      @Override public void myInterfaceMethod() {}
       ^ 
  (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
1 error
```

Comment: **Why**? Java 1.5 was released September 30, 2004. What is the purpose of maintaining strict compatibility at the source level with such an old version?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Which java versions I choose to make my code compatible with is a judgement call, and not the point.  My concern is that I would like to be able to make/publish a simple and accurate statement about what range of java compiler versions my source code is compatible with, for people who may compile it with various compiler versions.  Currently I seem to have no way of telling whether my code is 1.5 compliant or not.

Comment: @DonHatch you can download a Java SE5 JDK from oracles website. I have linked it at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [Oracle's documentation of `javac` for Java SE8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) it says:

> ...
>
> **-source *release***
>
> Specifies the version of source code accepted. The following values for release are allowed:
>
> ...
>
> - **1.5**
>
>   The compiler accepts code containing generics and other language features introduced in Java SE 5.
> - **5**
>
>   Synonym for 1.5.
> - **1.6**
>
>   No language changes were introduced in Java SE 6. However, encoding errors in source files are now reported as errors instead of warnings as in earlier releases of Java Platform, Standard Edition.
>
> ...

Notice that the site says that "*no language changes were introduced in Java SE 6"*. Thus, the fact that `@Override` could be used to assert that interface-methods were overridden seems to be not regarded as a language change; rather, the fact that it wasn't previously allowed may be regarded as simply a bug in some Java 5 SDKs compilers.

This behaviour is rectified since [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Override.html) can be omitted after compilation and the JDK 8 compiler understands (and validates) the annotation. Thus, the annotation has no effect whatsoever on the created bytecode.

With `-source 1.4`, we get a compilation error since [Annotations were introduced with Java 1.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation), thus including annotations that are retained at runtime could change the behaviour of the program and the compiler must not ignore them.

---

If we want to find all incompatibilites with Java SE 5, I recommend downloading [Java SE5 JDK from the Oracle Archive](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-javase5-downloads.html) and trying to compile the project with this JDK.